# Выполнение общего кода для каждой команды pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, telegram, telebot, декоратор

есть телеграм-бот с кучей команд.

```
import telebot

mytoken=...
adminchat_id=...

bot = telebot.TeleBot(mytoken)

@bot.message_handler(commands = ['command1', 'command2'])
def func1(message):
    ....

@bot.message_handler(commands = ['command3', 'command4'])
def func2(message):
    ....

@bot.message_handler(commands = ['command99', 'command100'])
def func50(message):
    ....
```

Понадобилось переправлять все запросы пользователей боту по любой команде определенному пользователю. Добавил функцию

```
def resend_message(msg):
    bot.send_message(adminchat_id, str(msg.from_user.username)+ ' ' + str(msg.from_user.first_name) + ' ' + str(msg.from_user.last_name) + '\n' + msg.text)
```

и прописал ее вызов (resend_message(message))в начало каждой func1 ... func50. Но может можно выполнить общий код для всех команд одной строчкой, не прописывая в каждую функцию?

Comment: Команды именно такого формата? То есть сама команды и после числа? Или команды очень разные?

Comment: разные, тут просто для примера с числами

Comment: В таком случае только commands=['command...', 'command...'] со всеми командами

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, скажу, что `msg.from_user.username` и *(по-моему)* `msg.from_user.last_name` может быть `None`, так что рекомендую сделать проверку на это, иначе бот иногда может выдавать ошибки

Во-вторых, если вы хотите общую функцию для всех функций, то могли бы все вписать в одну функцию:

```
@bot.message_handler()
def func_with_resend_message():
    resend_message(message)
    
    if message.text.lstrip('/').lower() == 'command1':
     return command1func(message)
    if message.text.lstrip('/').lower() == 'command2':
     return command2func(message)
```

и так далее

Либо же можно воспользоваться предложенным мною вариантом, но сделать это более интересно, взяв один из ответов в https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168340/using-a-dictionary-to-select-function-to-execute

Comment: Да, была мысль в один handler все запихать, просто думал, может быть есть механизм выполнения общего кода для всех handler. А с None в полях, именно поэтому там везде через str(), а не напрямую.

Answer (score 0):

Решение найдено, достаточно было почитать документацию)

```
telebot.apihelper.ENABLE_MIDDLEWARE = True
```

...

```
@bot.middleware_handler(update_types=['message'])
def modify_message(bot_instance, message):
    resend_message(message)
```

...